# PHP parsing xml issues with get values

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xpath

I receive file as xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Document xmlns="http://adress1" xmlns:adr="http://adress2" xmlns:inst="adress3" xmlns:meta="adress4" xmlns:oso="adress5" xmlns:str="adress6" xmlns:xsi="adress7">
    <str:DataDocument>
        <str:Head/>
        <meta:Date typeDate="created">
             <meta:Time>2014-07-23T12:35:20+02:00</meta:Time>
        </meta:Date>
    </str:DataDocument>
    <contentDocument format="text/xml" coding="xml">
        <Values>
            <Attachments>
                  <str:Attachment format="text/html" code="base64" nameFile="name.html">
                       <str:DataAttachment>VALUESRECEIVE</str:DataAttachment>
                   </str:Attachment>
                   <str:Attachment format="text/xml" code="base64" nameFile="name.xml">
                       <str:DataAttachment>VALUESToRECEIVE</str:DataAttachment>
                   </str:Attachment>
                   <str:Attachment format="text/xml" code="base64" nameFile="name2.xml">
                       <str:DataAttachment>VALUESToRECEIVE</str:DataAttachment>
                   </str:Attachment>
             </Attachments>
         </Values>
    </contentDocument>
    (...)
</Document>
```

I have to receive all nodes: `<str:DataAttachment>` and `<str:DataAttachment>` for each `<str:Attachment>`.

I wrote this:

```
$attachment = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($file1));
//first way
$res = $attachment->xpath('contentDocument/Values/Attachments/*');
//second way            
$zalacznikiListFromXml = $attachment->contentDocument->Values->Attachments;
foreach ($attachmentListFromXml as $Attachments){
    foreach($Attachmentsas $strAttachment)
        $attachToDecode = $strAttachment['str:DataAttachment'];
}
```

But both `xpath` and `$attachment->contentDocument->Values->Attachments` return empty object.

I don't know what is problem. Can you help me get to every str:DataAttachment?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elaborating on @Ghost's answer...

There are a couple of reasons why your "first way" isn't working.

1. Most of the elements in your input XML are in the default namespace, which is the namespace whose URI is `"http://adress1"`. This is because the outermost element has the default namespace declaration `xmlns="http://adress1"`. So this default namespace is inherited by all the elements that don't have an explicit namespace prefix. Therefore in order to select these elements in XPath, you have to tell XPath that you want elements in the namespace whose URI is `"http://adress1"`. Ghost showed how to declare a namespace prefix and use it in your XPath.  For the `adress1` namespace you might use `$attachment->registerXPathNamespace('ns1', 'http://adress1');`
2. Secondly, `$attachment->xpath('contentDocument/...')` doesn't match the structure of the input document. `$attachment` holds the root node of the input document, which is the invisible parent of `<Document>`. Then you're trying to select a child of the root node named `contentDocument`. But `<contentDocument>` is a child of `<Document>`, not of the root node. So you need something like `$attachment->xpath('/*/ns1:contentDocument/ns1:Values/ns1:Attachments/*');`

Comment: +1 for comprehensive explanation. helped me too as well

Answer (score 2):

If you opt to use xpath, use need to register the namespace first. Use `registerXPathNamespace`

Example:

```
$attachToDecode = array();
$attachment = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($file1));
$attachment->registerXPathNamespace('str', 'adress6');
foreach($attachment->xpath('//str:DataAttachment') as $strAttachment) {
    $attachToDecode[] = (string) $strAttachment;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($attachToDecode);
```

Sample Output:

```
VALUESRECEIVE
VALUESToRECEIVE
VALUESToRECEIVE
```